# Having trouble gulping, what is wrong with my gulpfile that copies and renames files?

Tags: gulp

My default task is to execute the "step2" task, which depends on step1. Step1 copies over a bunch of files, step2 is supposed to rename a single file, "file1.txt". My default task says to just do "step2". I am using gulp-rename.

```
gulp.task('step1', function() {
        var files = [
            './folder1/**/*.*',
            './file1.txt'
        ];

        return gulp.src(files, {base: "."})
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
});

gulp.task('step2', ['step1'], function() {
    gulp.src('./build/file1.txt')
    .pipe(rename("./renamed-file1.txt"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
});
```

The problem is I don't see a renamed file at all, and instead I see both the copy of the file I copied over and the renamed file. How do I fix this?

Also, why is it that for "./renamed-file1.txt", I have to specify it that way to ensure it gets in the build directory as opposed to ./build/renamed-file1.txt?

Answer (score 0):

The gulp-rename plugin renames the files in the stream not the ones in the file system: I guess you should split your step1 in to 2 gulp flows renaming your file while copying it.